# XML Serialization error: 2 types both use the XML type name, 'Relationship', from namespace ''

Tags: c#, xml, exception, xml-serialization

I am having a problem serializing via XML because 2 clases use a class (although different classes!) called Relationship. I have tried decorating 1 of the classes with another name using the XML attribute but it still gives me the following error:

> {"Types 'SiteServer.Relationship' and 'LocalServer.Relationship' both use the XML type name, 'Relationship', from namespace ''. Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type."}

Here are my 2 classes, anyone know why ?? AM i using the wrong attribute? It seems to be ignoring it :-)

```
public class SiteServer
{
    [XmlRoot("SiteServerRelationShip")]
    public class Relationship
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Relationship Relate = new Relationship();
}

public class LocalServer
{
    public class Relationship
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Relationship Relate = new Relationship();
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Decorate your two classes by an XmlRoot like this :

```
[XmlRoot("SiteServer", Namespace="http://example.com/schemas/SiteServer")]
public class SiteServer
{        
    [XmlRoot("SiteServerRelationShip", Namespace="http://example.com/schemas/SiteServer")]
    public class Relationship
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Relationship Relate = new Relationship();
}

[XmlRoot("LocalServer", Namespace="http://example.com/schemas/LocalServer")]
public class LocalServer
{
    [XmlRoot("LocalServerRelationship", Namespace="http://example.com/schemas/LocalServer")]
    public class Relationship
    {
        public string type { get; set; }

    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Relationship Relate = new Relationship();
}
```

This will produce two different FQDN for the two RelationShip classes :

```
{http://example.com/schemas/LocalServer}LocalServerRelationShip
{http://example.com/schemas/SiteServer}SiteServerRelationShip
```

Comment: Perhaps as the question goes and its little scope, it be simple using XMLType(AnonymousType=true) on top of "public class Relationship"

Answer (score 6):

`[XmlRoot]` is only used for the root element of the document. You want to use `[XmlType]` on other types.

Also, you don't need `[Serializable]`. The XML Serializer ignores it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decorate the fields also, e.g.:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Relationship))]
public class SiteServer
{
    [XmlRoot("SiteServerRelationship", Namespace = "http://example.com/schemas/SiteServerRelationship")] 
    public class Relationship
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("SiteServerRelationship", Namespace="http://example.com/schemas/SiteServerRelationship")]       
    public Relationship Relate = new Relationship();
}


[XmlInclude(typeof(Relationship))]    
public class LocalServer
{
    [XmlRoot("LocalServerRelationship", Namespace = "http://example.com/schemas/LocalServerRelationship")] 
    public class Relationship
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("LocalServerRelationship", Namespace="http://example.com/schemas/LocalServerRelationship")] 
    public Relationship Relate = new Relationship();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with two 3rd party webservices I was consuming in one application.  Strangely, the dynamic runtime generation was fine (although it took 2 minutes), but sgen.exe got upset.

The solution was to use svcutil.exe...

```
svcutil.exe /t:xmlSerializer targetAssemblyOrExecutable  /out:targetAssemblyOrExecutable.XmlSerializers.dll.cs
```

Then use csc.exe to compile it.