# serialize same class from two service references

Tags: c#, class, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I'm trying to use XMLSerialize to generate a .xml from one of my class that contain member from two  third-party Service references.

I got this error on the XmlSerializer (since both third-party service have the same class name in their reference).

> Types 'ExternalServiceReference1.SameClass' and
>   'ExternalServiceReference2.SameClass' both use the XML type name,
>   'SameClass', from namespace 'http://blablabla/'. Use XML attributes to
>   specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type.

TestClass1 from ExternalServiceReference1 contain a member of type SameClass
TestClass2 from ExternalServiceReference2 also contain a member of type SameClass

My class look something like this :

```
using ExternalServiceReference1; // This is the first thrid-party service reference, that contain the TestClass1. 
using ExternalServiceReference2; // This is the second thrid-party service reference, that contain the TestClass2.

[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
    public TestClass1 testClass1;
    public TestClass2 TestClass2;
}

My test program : 

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(Foo.GetType());

        }
    }
```

My question :

How can I solve this, without modifying the reference.cs of both service references in my project ?

I have no trouble if the solution is to add attribute on my own class ( Foo ) or on the XmlSerializer call. 
But I don't want to change the reference.cs generated for the two external reference.

Comment: according to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967941/c-sharp-xml-serializable-error-2-types-both-use-the-xml-type-name-relatio) you should add the `XmlRoot` attribute to the class. Maybe it's possible to add it to the property? You can find more information about XmlRoot [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlroot.aspx)

Comment: You can try this as a last resort `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
            var xDoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json,"Foo");`

Comment: Default : You can only apply the XmlRootAttribute to a class, structure, enumeration, or interface. In my case, it's a property.

Comment: L.B : I need to have it serialize in XML, not json.

Comment: @Hockeymtl If you read my comment carefully as I did your question, you will see that it returns an Xml document(XDocument).

Comment: L.B Yeah sorry, i read it too fast. It is true that it return a xml document. Do you know any equivalent to your solution that would use .net class instead ? I cannot install add-in since this will be production code that do not permit it.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your quandary, this should help.

```
namespace XmlSerializerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Example exampleClass = new Example();
            exampleClass.someClass1 = new ext1.SomeClass(){ Value = "Hello" };
            exampleClass.someClass2 = new ext2.SomeClass(){ Value = "World" };

            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Example));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(Console.Out, exampleClass);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "RootNode", Namespace = "http://fooooo")]
    public class Example
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value1", Type = typeof(ext1.SomeClass), Namespace = "ext1")]
        public ext1.SomeClass someClass1 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value2", Type = typeof(ext2.SomeClass), Namespace = "ext2")]
        public ext2.SomeClass someClass2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<RootNode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http:
//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://fooooo">
  <Value1 xmlns="ext1">
    <Value>Hello</Value>
  </Value1>
  <Value2 xmlns="ext2">
    <Value>World</Value>
  </Value2>
</RootNode>
```